# How to return a function and then call it later?

Tags: function, return, d, return-type

So lets say I have this struct a and a void method that takes that struct in as a parameter. How would I be able to return the void method through another method and then call it later?

The code I have looks like this:

```
struct Script{
    //variables
}

void foo(Script e)
{

}

function getfoo()
{
    return foo;
}

void main(string[] args)
{

    writeln("Hello World!");
    stdin.readln();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import std.stdio;

struct Script
{
    int x, y;
}

void foo(Script e)
{
    writeln("Got: ", e);
}

void function(Script e) getfoo()
{
    return &foo;
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    auto func = getfoo();
    func(Script(1, 2));
}
```

Comment: I love how they changed the way types are defined in D.